# How to create a new ratio based on a "long" dataset

Tags: r, data-manipulation

Here is a sample dataset:

```
structure(list(LD_wday = c(6, 2, 6, 1, 4, 4, 7, 6, 1, 3, 1, 3, 
6, 1, 6, 4, 7, 7, 6, 2, 7, 1, 5, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 5, 1, 2, 5, 1, 
6, 3, 4, 3, 4, 1, 6, 3, 6, 2, 6, 5, 5, 4, 3, 5, 6), status = c("successful", 
"failed", "live", "successful", "failed", "successful", "failed", 
"successful", "successful", "successful", "live", "successful", 
"successful", "failed", "failed", "successful", "failed", "live", 
"successful", "successful", "failed", "live", "successful", "successful", 
"failed", "successful", "successful", "successful", "failed", 
"failed", "failed", "failed", "failed", "successful", "live", 
"failed", "live", "successful", "successful", "successful", "successful", 
"failed", "failed", "live", "successful", "failed", "successful", 
"failed", "failed", "successful")), row.names = c(NA, -50L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

So based on the image below, I am trying to figure out how to create a ratio of successful/failed. 
[image: sample output]

I keep using group_by & summarize but I end up with something like the output below.  How do I create the success/fail ratio from the dataset thats provided?

```
sample %>%
  filter(status == "failed" | status == "successful") %>%
  group_by(LD_wday, status) %>%
  summarize(count = n())

OUTPUT:
# A tibble: 13 x 3
# Groups:   LD_wday [7]
   LD_wday status     count
     <dbl> <chr>      <int>
 1       1 failed         3
 2       1 successful     3
 3       2 failed         4
 4       2 successful     3
 5       3 failed         1
 6       3 successful     5
 7       4 failed         2
 8       4 successful     4
 9       5 failed         4
10       5 successful     2
11       6 failed         2
12       6 successful     7
13       7 failed         3
```

Any help would be appreciated and I apologize for having difficulty articulating my problem.

Comment: what is your expected output.  do you need `%>% mutate(status = count/sum(count))`

Comment: Do you want to count overall ratio or ratio for each `LD_wday`. Can you show your expected output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we want to create a ratio of the two, then we can divide by the `sum` of 'count' as it is already grouped by 'LD_wday'

```
library(dplyr)
sample %>%
  filter(status == "failed" | status == "successful") %>%
  group_by(LD_wday, status) %>%
  summarize(count = n()) %>%
   mutate(status = count/sum(count))
```